# {come to know / find out / notice / see}

Tags: word-choice

Consider this expression

> After I **came to know/found out** the fact that two of my friends will not be able to make it to the party, I decided to call it off.
>
> Every time I **come to know/find out/notice/see** that water level in the can is below X level, I call the store and they get it replaced

For these two expressions which of the phrases are correct? Is there any difference between the meanings of **notice/see/find out/come to know**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest "learned" for the first sentence instead of all those other choices:

> After I **learned** that two of my friends **would** not be able to {make it to / come to / attend [CHOOSE ONE]} the party, I decided to call it off.

And for the second sentence, I'd suggest this:

> Every time **I {notice / see [CHOOSE ONE]** that the water level in the can is below X level, I call the store and they {replace it / fill it up [CHOOSE ONE]}.

*I {come to know/find out}* are verbose.